# iCalendar implementation on android?

Tags: java, android, icalendar

I want to hook up an application to work with the iCalendar format for calendering.  Is there native support in the Android SDK for this? If not, is there an open source library anyone is familiar with?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ical4j to parse ics file in java. see https://ical4j.github.io/ (or google it if they move again and the link is no longer valid)

As far as I know there is nothing to prevent it from working with android

Comment: Link is no longer valid

Comment: @Matthew there you go